# Making custom icons in CSS using SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, mapbox

I am trying to use my own icons in a css file to display icons on a react website.
Below is the code that leads up to the point where I actually create the markers (I am using MapBox API. (See bottom of code)

The problem is that
a.) when i create my own SVG files in illustrator and either put them in the project directory or make a link for them for the file to reference, neither appear in my map.
b.) I found someone else's icon and used that, and it can render that icon, but it is way too big.

```
import React from "react";
import mapboxgl, { LngLat } from "mapbox-gl";
import "./GoogleMap.css";

import db from "../../firebaseConfig";
import { Marker } from "react-simple-maps";
var image01 = require("../../assets/droneIcon.png");
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");

const auth = require("../../auth.json");

mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "pk.eyJ1IjoiamVycnkyMDE4IiwiYSI6ImNrNjA1N3d5NTA0Zmwza252OXNpcWpzYWEifQ.lBwSxATvYgUqiyGfIvC3tw";

class GoogleMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lng: 50,
      lat: 50,
      zoom: 10
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;

    var droneList = [];

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom
    });

    map.on("move", () => {
      const { lng, lat } = map.getCenter();

      this.setState({
        lng: lng.toFixed(4),
        lat: lat.toFixed(4),
        zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2)
      });
    });

    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appliance-1/100/Drone-07-512.png)';
    el.style.width = "500px";
    el.style.height = "500px";
```

I have tried creating my own SVG, making a raw git file for it to host and reference it, however I can't find anywhere to make that minified raw SVG file into a readable image for the javascript code. I have found that SVG files that are created by others and posted can be placed into the map api and successfully display.

I need to either
1. Find a way to display SVG images, since the current methods I have been trying are resulting in blank images, or just the alpha channel of the image

2. Find a way to simply resize the icon that does render, so that I can keep it at the necessary pixel dimensions without having it be too large for my application.

Any help is very much appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: `creating my own SVG, making a raw git file for it to host and reference it,` ??? I'm pretty sure you didn't mean what I understand, because that's just bonkers. This and a few more places in your question make me wonder what's up with all these buzzwords. You sound like a marketeer, where at times the combinations of buzz-/keywords makes no sense at all. Plus I read like 3 different Problems to solve in this one question. So calm down, take a deep breath and try to rephrase this. Explain in simple terms what exctly the problem is that you're trying to solve; one Problem at the time.

Comment: Where are you even using an SVG image or code? I see a reference to a couple `.png` files.

Comment: @DrewReese my bad- the code I pasted in has a png where the .svg normally goes, but that is where the file reference needs to be.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry if the phrasing is weird here. I need an SVG file for an icon in my code. There are two options for the program to reference that SVG file; either it is stored locally in the program's directory, or it simply looks at a url for it. That's what I meant by making a raw git file to host the file in a web browser, where the program would then reference that link.

Comment: Do you by any chance happen to have a copy of the SVG file? It's just a plain text XML file essentially. I usually copy the code into and create a react "Icon" component for display. If you can, then you can also certainly fiddle with the `viewbox`, `width`, and `height` values.

Comment: @Thomas as far as the other issue i discuss here, I am saying that in the event that I can't get my own icon displaying on the map, I have found some links that when plugged into the "url" field (see bottom of code) are able to successfully display an icon. If I want to just use one of these icons, the secondary issue I'm having with them is that they are way too big for the map- just asking for tips on how to resize while keeping the same pixel count :) thanks for the response

Comment: @DrewReese That's essentially what I tried to do; I exported the icon as an SVG in illustrator, then uploaded that .svg file to git gist and tried to follow this tutorial so I could make a link that my code would use to reference it. https://www.sitepoint.com/why-hosting-your-svgs-is-hard-and-how-to-beat-it/ however, if you read the tutorial, you'll notice that the final step is no longer possible since the site is no longer active. All I'm asking is if someone knows an alternative way to get a custom svg file representing a marker in the mapbox api in react, since I've tried everything.

Comment: I meant, fiddle with the size/etc to get it how you want, and then importing it like a local asset, like any other image file. Have you already tried that?

Comment: @DrewReese I would try that, but for some reason, when I download an image as a png, place it in the directory of the project, and then reference that downloaded image (that was previously appearing right in its url form), it instead seems to show the background of the image. If it has no background it will show nothing, if it is a figure over a red background it will show a red square, etc. I tried testing if it might just be showing a corner of the photo (if the height/width are too small), however even with massive height and width directions it simply returns the background

Comment: There may be something weird going on with the PNG download. Does the image look correct if you just open it in a viewer? (drag n' drop to an empty browser tab) If you have the raw **SVG** asset then you can change any of the SVG attributes as you need, color, fill, stroke, etc... If you share the SVG DOM (or link to it) here I can try to provide more assistance as this comment conversation has gone on too long with little progress.

Comment: The PNG looks fine when opened in a browser or normal preview viewer. https://gist.github.com/andrewm898/c6fdefacabe51b7d3f442f889835135d Here is a link to the git gist of the SVG file- thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> I need an SVG file for an icon in my code. There are two options for
>   the program to reference that SVG file; either it is stored locally in
>   the program's directory, or it simply looks at a url for it.

When referencing an SVG in CSS, you can use an inline **Data URI**.

Instead of the protocol:

```
https://
```

you'll need to begin your Data URI with MIME Type and encoding:

```
data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
```

But after that, you can add the SVG without any changes:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 120"><path d="M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z" fill="rgb(188, 187, 187)" /><path d="M38.8 68.4l37.8 7.9 1.6-7.6-37.8-7.9-1.6 7.6zm5-18l35 16.3 3.2-7-35-16.4-3.2 7.1zm9.7-17.2l29.7 24.7 4.9-5.9-29.7-24.7-4.9 5.9zm19.2-18.3l-6.2 4.6 23 31 6.2-4.6-23-31zM38 86h38.6v-7.7H38V86z" fill="rgb(244, 128, 35)" /></svg>
```

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 120"><path d="M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z" fill="rgb(188, 187, 187)" /><path d="M38.8 68.4l37.8 7.9 1.6-7.6-37.8-7.9-1.6 7.6zm5-18l35 16.3 3.2-7-35-16.4-3.2 7.1zm9.7-17.2l29.7 24.7 4.9-5.9-29.7-24.7-4.9 5.9zm19.2-18.3l-6.2 4.6 23 31 6.2-4.6-23-31zM38 86h38.6v-7.7H38V86z" fill="rgb(244, 128, 35)" /></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```